# How can I set up mod_rewrite in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I set up mod_rewrite? My directory structure is bellow for(www.example.com/user/account/)

```
index.php
.htaccess
```

.htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /user/account/
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?command=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```

I can access `www.example.com/user/account/setting`  where `command =setting`

but i can't access `www.example.com/user/account/setting/`  where `command =setting`

when i change

```
 RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?command=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

i can not access  `www.example.com/user/account/setting/1`  where `command =setting & page = 1`

**please help how can i access below link?**

```
www.example.com/user/account/setting/1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a new rule for handling `page` parameter by capturing it from pretty URI:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /user/account/

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?command=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?command=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```